Should a non-core college degree be listed on a resume?
I’m a self-taught web-developer with over 3 years of experience in the industry. I learnt most of the stuff on my own. Yes, I took various courses, but I didn't fully complete them (except for the internship in my first company).
Besides that, I have a degree in linguistics and literature. Even though I attended the university for five years, I am only a bachelor (because my country doesn’t follow the Bologna system). Hence, the question is: should I put the information about my degree in the CV? On one hand, the section about your eduction is crucial in any resume. On the other hand, I’m afraid that in the eyes of the recruiter, this could demote me as a professional.

"Even though I attended the university for five years, I am only a bachelor" - do make sure that this is the common way your degree is "translated" into Bologna system degrees.

Considering the international nature of many web applications, it seems linguistics could be directly relevant to the field.

A degree with decent grades demonstrates that you have learned how to learn, even if it's in a different field.
And the employer may actually have a use for some of the skills that degree implies. Linguistics and literature implies that you might be able to write better than average documentation, for example, or help them get docs translated.
I'd say listing it is far better than leaving the impression that you're less educated, especially since you probably would have to explain what you were doing during those years anyway.
It may not help you much. But leaving it out may hurt you.
(Back in the seventies it was a truism that any MIT grad could get a programming job no matter what their degree, because programmers were scarce and employers trusted that someone with those credentials could learn.)

Honesty on a resume is a good thing.
As a small business owner (25 people 6 to 8 developers), I always look for additional areas that a person has education. Yes, it may not directly make their code better, but it provides a better picture of the whole person.
This is a different perspective than @Hilmar, which I don't understand that answer was downvoted.
Under the section for education, a single line may provide an interesting nuget.

There is something called "screening theory" that argues for putting your utterly unrelated degree on your resume. You spent 4 or 5 years showing up to class on time, handing in assignments on time, doing most of what you were supposed to do on the assignment, studying for exams, showing up to the exams on time, and demonstrating that you remembered and understood the stuff you were supposed to remember and understand. Those are skills not everyone has! Think about the people you met in first year who didn't finish the degree. (Screening theory actually claims that university doesn't teach you these skills or anything else useful, simply identifies the people who can do this, who are generally good employees. But you don't have to agree with that to see how completing a degree shows good things about you.) Including it will be a positive. Perhaps only a small positive - you weren't taught the specific information a CS degree teaches - but a positive.
What's more, you're considering just putting nothing for that time period. If you have items on your resume before that, a multi year gap will look suspicious -- were you in a coma? in jail? busy being a drug dealer? and could cost you the interview. If you have nothing before that, people might assume you are much younger than you are and when they meet you, may suddenly be "wait, you're like 25, what have you been doing the last 8 or 10 years?"
I would put the degree on with as little info as possible. If it's a BA, just say that, don't mention the linguistics and literature. If you won any awards or whatnot, mention them. Focus on the work experience you have and why it makes you a great fit for this job. But don't leave a big blank gap where you actually have something to be proud of, something that for at least some recruiters will help you get the interview.


should I put the information about my degree in the CV?

Yes.
Your resume is expected to give a complete history of what you've done as an adult even if it's not relevant to the job. Gaps always attract attention and large gaps will attract A LOT of attention.
If you leave it off, the interviewer or recruiter will ask themselves "what the heck did Lazouski do for 5 years?". If the info is not on the resume they will probably take a guess at it and whatever they come up with will be way worse than a non-relevant degree. It's in your own best interest to get in front of it.
There is no need to be prominent about it either: a simple one-liner will do.

YMMV. Personally I think that a 5 year gap will attract a lot of negative attention.


On one hand, the section about your eduction is crucial in any resume

No, it's not.
What is crucial in a resumé is information which helps you in getting an interview. If you think your degree will help you get an interview, include it. If it won't, exclude it (or just make it a very brief bullet point).

A CV and a resume are two very different things with different purposes and are used differently in different countries. A CV is supposed to be a full list of your training and work history. (I've heard that a CV is expected in European companies.) A resume is a marketing document with the purpose of getting an interview. A resume is expected by US companies. In many cases, a person applying at a US company will prepare a resume specifically for that company.
The question then is: where are you intending to send the document? If to a US company, then prepare a resume for that company.
